# Não consigo colocar uma imagem acima do menu

Tags: html

Tenho trabalhado com um [código semipronto HTML](http://www.templatescreme.com/demo/bootstrap-classic-responsive/540) e eu gostaria de colocar uma imagem justamente acima do menu da pagina, onde tenho o logo da minha empresa, mas eu nao consigo colocar a imagem de forma alguma, e este site ai, a barra azul esta no lugar onde eu quero a minha imagem. Alguém pode ajudar por favor ?

```
<body id="pageBody" oncontextmenu="return false">
```

*** ESTA É A IMAGEM QUE QUERO ACIMA DO MENU ***

```
 <img src="images/cabecalho tauri.fw.png" alt=""/>
```

```
<div id="decorative2">
<div class="container">

    <div class="divPanel topArea notop nobottom">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12">

                <div id="divLogo" class="pull-left">
                    <a href="index.html" id="divSiteTitle"></a><br />
                    <a href="index.html" id="divTagLine"></a>
                </div>

                <div id="divMenuRight" class="pull-right">
                <div class="navbar">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar-highlight btn-large btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                        NAVIGATION <span class="icon-chevron-down icon-white"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills ddmenu">

                            <li class="dropdown active"><a href="index.html">Início</a></li>

                            <li class="dropdown"><a href="quem_somos.html">Quem Somos</a></li>

                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="todos_servicos.html" class="dropdown-toggle">Serviços <b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                        <li><a href="todos_servicos.html">Todos os Serviços</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Suporte Técnico</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Gerenciamento de Sistemas</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Consultoria & Gestão Tecnológica</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">

                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">Manutenção de Ativos &nbsp;&raquo;</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Servidores</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Workstations</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Laptop & Desktop</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Redes de Computadores</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">UPS</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        </li>
                        </ul>
                            </li>


                            <li class="dropdown"><a href="portfolio.html">Portfólio de Clientes</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown"><a href="contact.php">Contato</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Seria algo assim? http://jsfiddle.net/shail/YKaBK/show/

Comment: Esse exemplo acabou me ajudando @Dherik, obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

o certo seria setar a imagem onde está descrito "YOUR NAME HERE", e que a imagem não fosse tão grande,para que o design responsivo seja usado efetivamente.